# Google Translate iframes too wide on mobile

Tags: mobile, google-translate

I'm using the Google Translate widget ( http://translate.google.com/manager/website/ ) on my website. It works fine on the desktop screen, but it uses the exact same layout on mobile and other small screens, and looks terrible. For one thing, the iframe containing the list of languages has a hard-coded width of 860 pixels. You can't select any languages beyond the 3rd column because they're off the edge of the screen (and you can't scroll to the right to see them because the browser doesn't realize that the iframe is too wide -- I assume it's the same problem as discussed here: [Webpage with wide iframe is not scrollable on an iPhone with viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122744/webpage-with-wide-iframe-is-not-scrollable-on-an-iphone-with-viewport) ).

I've looked into fixing the problem using CSS, but CSS can't "see" inside iframes. I've searched all over stackoverflow and the rest of the internet, and not only have I not found a solution, I haven't been able to find anyone else complaining about the problem. I can't be the only one, can I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling Google Translate widget for mobile websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027360/styling-google-translate-widget-for-mobile-websites)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: Instead of "Dropdown only" layout, I chose "Horizontal". When you do that, Google uses a simple drop-down list instead of a big iframe.

The little panel that appear at the top of the page is still too wide to display properly, however, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: how can u change the width? that's the problem I am having

Comment: @david-brierton use CSS - add a "width" setting to ".goog-te-combo"